# Mule Server - application code to be deployed in standalone folder

Tags: deployment, mule

Our Mule 3 server is installed at "/mule/instance0/" on our UNIX server and the application is deployed under "/mule/instance0/apps/" folder. We have been deploying a zip file into the "/mule/instance0/apps/" folder and application runs fine.

There is a new requirement to deploy the application zip file in a folder other than "/mule/instance0/apps" folder (say "/tmp"). We tried looking for the changes that need to be made and they were rather humongous. Does anybody know of a simple config change to pick the application code from a folder other than "/mule/instance0/apps" ?

Thanks,
Midhun

Answer (score 1):

You can make apps directory a symbolic link to tmp: `$cd $MULE_HOME; rm -rf apps; ln -s /tmp apps`